# fire event by click a control inside accordion

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, accordion

I have an Accordion that populate from database.
If I click on a static control such a Button, event fires. But if I create dynamic Control Like LinkButton inside Accordion, event not works.

on top of page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

aspx:

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="false" RequireOpenedPane="false" OnItemCommand="Accordion1_ItemCommand" ></ajaxToolkit:Accordion>

aspx.cs:

```
Page_Load:
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateAcrDynamically();
        }

    private void PopulateAcrDynamically()
    {
        str_cmd = "Some Query";
        //create connection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str_cmd, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            Label lbl_crsTitle;
            AccordionPane pane;
            int paneID = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr_crs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                lbl_crsTitle = new Label();
                lbl_crsTitle.ToolTip = dr_crs["Crs_ID"].ToString();
                pane = new AccordionPane();
                pane.ID = "Pane" + paneID;
                pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lbl_crsTitle);

                str_cmd = "Another Query";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str_cmd, con);
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    LinkButton lnkbtn_topicTitle;
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        lnkbtn_topicTitle = new LinkButton();
                        lnkbtn_topicTitle.Text = dr["Tpc_FaTitle"].ToString();
                        lnkbtn_topicTitle.Click += new EventHandler(lnkbtn_topicTitle_Click);
                        lnkbtn_topicTitle.CommandName = "Select";
                        lnkbtn_topicTitle.CommandArgument = "<%# (int)Eval('" + dr["Tpc_ID"].ToString() + "') %>";
                        pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(lnkbtn_topicTitle);
                    }
                }
                Accordion1.Panes.Add(pane);
                ++paneID;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void lnkbtn_topicTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //LinkButton lnkbtn_topicTitle = (LinkButton)Accordion1.FindControl("lnkbtn_topicTitle");
        //Alert lnkbtn_topicTitle.Text;
    }
```

I also try this for Header and content:

```
    protected void Accordion1_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            var companyId = e.CommandArgument;
            LinkButton lnkbtn_topicTitle = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtn_topicTitle") as LinkButton;
            //Alert lnkbtn_topicTitle.Text;
        }
    }
```